# Drawing a border in PdfFlowDocument using Xfinium.PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

I'd like to draw a border around a piece of text, let's say a paragraph. The idea is to have something looking like a box with text in it.

I'm using Xfinium.PDF for UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can include the text in a one cell table and set the border on the table
   or
2. You can draw the text in a form XObject, draw any kind of graphics around the text and then insert the form XObject in a flow document.

Comment: Thank you Mihai. I chose the option #1. This is my code:

Comment: var table = new PdfFlowTableContent(1);
table.OuterMargins = new PdfFlowContentMargins(0, 0, 6, 0);
table.Border = new PdfPen(PdfRgbColor.Black, 0.5);

PdfFlowTableRow row = table.Rows.Add();
var cell = new PdfFlowTableStringCell(text) { InnerMargins = cellPadding, Font = fontText, Multiline = true };
row.Cells.Add(cell);

document.AddContent(table);

Comment: There is a problem with the option #1 though. The text is very dense as it does not have LineSpacing. Including a paragraph instead of plain text would do the trick but I don't know how to include a paragraph in a PdfFlowTableContent.

Comment: Create a PdfFlowTextContent object then create a composite cell to include it. The flow text content supports various formatting options.